# How do I create a shortcode for widget in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, widget, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I want to create a shortcode for my widget.

This is my code for creating a widget, if I want to create a shortcode for this widget what do I do?

```
<pre>
function my_slider_post() {
    register_widget('my_slider_post');
    }
    add_action('widgets_init','my_slider_post');




class my_slider_post extends WP_Widget {
    function my_slider_post() {

        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'my_slider_post','description' => __('Widget display Slider Post','theme'));
         add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'scripts'));
        parent::__construct('mysliderpost',__('my Slider Post','theme'),$widget_ops);

        }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        /* User-selected settings. */
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
    $img1 = $instance['image_one'];
    $title1 = $instance['title_one'];
    $desc1 = $instance['desc_one'];
    $img2 = $instance['image_two'];
    $img3 = $instance['image_three'];

        /* Before widget (defined by themes). */
        echo $before_widget;

        /* Title of widget (before and after defined by themes). */
        if ( $title )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;



<!-- start -->

// code html to show





        /* After widget (defined by themes). */
        echo $after_widget;

    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        /* Strip tags (if needed) and update the widget settings. */
            $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
            $instance['image_one'] = $new_instance['image_one'];
            $instance['title_one'] = $new_instance['title_one'];
            $instance['desc_one'] = $new_instance['desc_one'];
            $instance['image_two'] = $new_instance['image_two'];
            $instance['image_three'] = $new_instance['image_three'];

        return $instance;
    }
    public function scripts()
    {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'media-upload' );
       wp_enqueue_media();
       wp_enqueue_script('our_admin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/our_admin.js', array('jquery'));
    }
    public function form( $instance ) {
    // code html to show on widget into sidebar control panel 

     }



    }



</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your widget class "my_slider_post " you can use this code:

```
<?php add_shortcode( 'show_slider', 'slider_shortcode' );
function slider_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // Configure defaults and extract the attributes into variables
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array( 
            'type'   => 'my_slider_post '
            //you can add here more parameters below
        ),
        $atts
    ));

    $args = array( //optional markup:
        'before_widget' => '<div class="box widget scheme-' . $scheme . ' ">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<div class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</div>',
    );

    ob_start();
    the_widget( $type, $atts, $args );
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

and then use this code

```
[show_slider]
```

to run the widget.

I used this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/inserting-widgets-with-shortcodes/

Answer (score 0):

Add

`add_shortcode('the_slider_short_code', 'my_slider_post');` after `class my_slider_post extends WP_Widget` and call shortcode as `[the_slider_short_code]` in your post, page or custom post type.

Alternatively you can use [amr shortcode](http://wordpress.org/plugins/amr-shortcode-any-widget/) plugin to generate shortcode for any widgets. You can [read more about it from here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-wordpress-widgets-in-post-and-page-content/).

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Zipal_ Thank you for your answer bro, 
i did what you told me i made add_shortcode('the_slider_short_code', 'my_slider_post'); after class my_slider_post extends WP_Widget  and when i call shortcode as [the_slider_short_code]  in my custom post type or my post  nothing work !!


PS : i know amr shortcode but i need to create shortcode without it